# C# login function implemented using SignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement a login function using the SignInManager I tried the below code Everytime the

> result.Succeeded

is failed. I cannot figureout whats wrong. The model state is valid and the database connection is also working.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    

public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName,
                model.UserPassword, model.RememberMe,false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (Request.Query.Keys.Contains("ReturnUrl"))
                {
                    return Redirect(Request.Query["ReturnUrl"].First());
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Shop", "Main");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to login");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: How did you register a user? Using the api or directly insert a user record in the database? The latter approach is wrong, because ASP.NET Identity will hash your password. So you cannot just insert your plain password into the database.

Comment: Directly inserting the user no api @TríNguyễn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly insert a user record with a plain password in the User table. You have to do it via the ASP.NET Identity register user api. See [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#examine-register)

For instance, if your password is helloworld, the library will hash it to some gibberish string. That is for security purpose, that it wouldn't compromise users' passwords if someone get access to the User table.

Comment: This works. The problem is with the register function Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `EmailConfirmed` as `True` in your AspNetUsers table like below:

[image]

result:

[image]

Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser-1.emailconfirmed?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.