# Why password checking always fail in ASP .NET Core Identity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm making a web application with ASP .NET Core 3.1. I'm using Identity to build user login function.

I'm getting a problem in which registered user can't login, due to password checking always fail. I went ahead and create an user programmatically, then check password right after the creation, and the check still fail.

Did I forget to set something up?

**More details:**

1. I want user with roles so I set up custom Identity service like this. I think I forgot to set up some extra thing here.

```cs
// In Startup class
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>((_options) =>
    {
        // Custom IdentityOptions configuration;
    })
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
   
    // ...
}
```

2. I tried create user programmatically and check the password right after that. The check still fail.

```cs
// In Startup.Configure() method

string username = "admin";
string password = "123456";

IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser(username);
await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

bool isCorrect = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);
// isCorrect is always false;
```

(I do make sure that the user is created successfully, and password is added successfully. I did view the database data and see the user there.)

I did check similar questions on StackOverflow, but their problem seems to be different from mine so it didn't help.

Comment: Does the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73546251/c-sharp-login-function-implemented-using-signinmanager/73553804#73553804) that I post solve  your question?

Comment: I set EmailConfirmed to `True` in data view, but still couldn't login. Do I need to have email set as well?

Comment: I think you need. Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), to know more about identity.

Comment: Check how to perform authentication in Identity, see [this link](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-authentication/).

Answer (score 1):

`UserManager.CreateAsync` method returns an `IdentityResult` that will tell you if user creation succeeded or not.

```
string username = "admin";
string password = "123456";

IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser(username);
IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

if (result.Succeded)
{
    
    var actualUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);

    if (actualUser != null)
    {
        bool isCorrect = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(actualUser, password);
    }
}
else
{
    // check what went wrong
    var errors = result.Errors;
}
```

User creation is probably failing because password is weak.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.createasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: As stated in question detail, I made sure user creation is successful. I see the user detail in database, with password hash.

Comment: Try to retrieve user using `UserManager.FindByNameAsync` and pass that user to `CheckPasswordAsync`.

Comment: Update: the issue solved itself after I restart Visual Studio.
I took a look at database data after that and see a different password hash (didn't touch code, just restart VS). I think the password got "stuck" and didn't update with the new password I set and check against.